# For Loop in module call with condition

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to find a way to iterate through a list of domains and then conditionally set an argument for only one of the domains.

I have a list of `zones` in my `.tfvars`:

```
dns_zone_names = [
abc.com
123.com
xyz.com
]
```

I then call a module that already uses `count` to determine environment. I need to iterate through the list of domains and set an argument *only* if it matches `123.com`:

```
module "dns_zones" {
  providers              = { my.provider }
  count                  = contains(["production", "test"], var.environment_type) ? 1 : 0
  source                 = "../my-modules"
  private_dns_zone_names = var.dns_zone_names
  resource_group_name    = var.name
  desired_argument        = // conditionally set boolean if zone in var.dns_zone_names == "123.com"
}
```

I was hoping a `for` loop in the `desired_argument` would work but can't seem to get syntax right (if it's possible at all). Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The question is slightly unclear as the module iteration is based on the `environment_type` enumeration, and therefore there would be no difference between iterating through the domains and using a conditional for the domain versus explictly passing the value since both would yield the same result in the module declaration

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewSchuchard - the only reason I mentioned the ```count``` for the ```environment_type``` enumeration was b/c I believe that prohibits me from using ```count``` again to evaluate condition for the ```desired_argument```.  The ```environment_type``` will have no bearing on the ```desired_argument```.

Comment: "I believe that prohibits me from using count again to evaluate condition for the desired_argument" Yes that is correct, and leads to the reason that you may as well just explicitly pass the parameter value to the module declaration as that would be exactly the same result.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not tracking. The count for ```environment_type``` determines if the zone resource is created at all based on that variable value ("production" or "test").  Still seems like I would need a way to iterate through ```dns_zone_names``` and then set the ```desired_argument``` to ```true``` for only the ```123.com```  zone.

Comment: Nm, I think I'm following now @MatthewSchuchard. Will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, I hope the following code helps.

```hcl
variable "desired_zone" {
  type        = string
  description = "Value of the desired DNS zone."
}

variable "dns_zone_names" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "List of DNS zones."
}

locals {
  containsDesiredZone = contains(var.dns_zone_names, var.desired_zone)
  domains             = local.containsDesiredZone ? var.dns_zone_names : []
}

# dummy resource
resource "null_resource" "validation" {
  for_each = toset(local.domains)

  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
    domain     = each.value
  }
}

output "contains_desired_zone" {
  value       = local.containsDesiredZone
  description = "A boolean indicating whether the desired zone is in the list of DNS zones"
}
```

### Test 1

Running the code with the following variables:

```hcl
desired_zone = "123.com"

dns_zone_names = [
  "abc.com",
  "123.com",
  "xyz.com"
]
```

Terraform plan output:

```txt
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.validation["123.com"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "validation" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "always_run" = (known after apply)
          + "domain"     = "123.com"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.validation["abc.com"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "validation" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "always_run" = (known after apply)
          + "domain"     = "abc.com"
        }
    }

  # null_resource.validation["xyz.com"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "validation" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + triggers = {
          + "always_run" = (known after apply)
          + "domain"     = "xyz.com"
        }
    }

Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + contains_desired_zone = true
```

### Test 2

Running the code with the following variables:

```hcl
desired_zone = "123.com"

dns_zone_names = [
  "abc.com",
  "123456.com",
  "xyz.com"
]
```

Terraform plan output:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
 + contains_desired_zone = false
```

(no resources created)